# Run jar with dependencies from the command line

Tags: java, jar

Java can run jar files from the command line like this:

```
java -jar foobar.jar
```

However, if `foobar.jar` depends on `baz.jar`, the above will throw an exception as soon as any of the classes in `baz.jar` is invoked, as the JVM has no way to know where to look for these.

However, the man page (OpenJDK 8 on Linux) states that:

> When you use the `-jar` option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.

If repackaging is not an option, is there a way to run a jar file with dependencies from the command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use `java -jar`, dependencies are not specified on the command line.
You have 2 ways to add jars to the class path:

1. Call `java` with the main class and add jar files, including your `foobar.jar`, on the command line:

   ```
   java -cp foobar.jar:baz.jar com.mycompany.MainClass
   ```
2. Include dependencies in `foobar.jar`'s manifest file (and then run `java -jar`)

   ```
   Class-Path: baz.jar
   ```

Comment: Does the colon need to be a semicolon on windows?

Comment: Yes, it does, @ThomasStokes

Comment: I try this but I get an error : "Could not find or load main class"
How can java find the main class name in the right package ?

Comment: @Nab Are you typing the fully qualified class name (with packages)? The only other reason would be that the class is not in the jar.

Comment: My bad, as I am running this on windows, the correct command is :
java -cp "MyJar.jar;lib\*" com.somepackage.subpackage.Main

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have only 'one' main class in foobar.jar. If it is more then 1, then you need to specify which one to execute.
You can simply set the classpath, before executing the jar

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/JAR_LOCATION/bar.jar
```

Comment: Yes, I have only one main class in `foobar.jar`, else the application wouldn’t even start. Adding `baz.jar` (I suppose that’s the one you mean) to `$CLASSPATH` didn’t help either (I suppose they mean it when they write in the docs that all other classpath settings are ignored).