# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I run the application (Hibernate, JPA) in IntelliJ IDEA, everything works without errors, but the jar file created by Maven when launched on the server gives an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Persistence

I don't know much about running the application on the server, please tell me what I'm missing. Dependencies have been added, the configuration seems to be all there too.

Here is my code:

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>corp1</id>
            <name>DataModel</name>
            <url>file:///home/sgt-user/.m2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>port-reader</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.sgt.EchoMultiServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Model:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "meter")
public class DataModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="imei")
    private String imei;

    @Column(name="readCycle")
    private int readCycle;

    @Column(name="dataCount")
    private int dataCount;

    @Column(name="volume")
    private double volume;

    @Column(name="interval1")
    private int interval1;

    @Column(name="interval2")
    private int interval2;

    @Column(name="interval3")
    private int interval3;

    @Column(name="batP")
    private int batP;

    @Column(name="batV")
    private int batV;

    @Column(name="chsum")
    private int chsum;

    public DataModel(){}

    public DataModel(String imei, int readCycle, int dataCount, double volume, int interval1, int interval2, int interval3, int batP, int batV, int chsum) {
        this.imei = imei;
        this.readCycle = readCycle;
        this.dataCount = dataCount;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.interval1 = interval1;
        this.interval2 = interval2;
        this.interval3 = interval3;
        this.batP = batP;
        this.batV = batV;
        this.chsum = chsum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof DataModel dataModel)) return false;
        return readCycle == dataModel.readCycle && dataCount == dataModel.dataCount && Double.compare(dataModel.volume, volume) == 0 && interval1 == dataModel.interval1 && interval2 == dataModel.interval2 && interval3 == dataModel.interval3 && batP == dataModel.batP && batV == dataModel.batV && chsum == dataModel.chsum && Objects.equals(id, dataModel.id) && Objects.equals(imei, dataModel.imei);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, imei, readCycle, dataCount, volume, interval1, interval2, interval3, batP, batV, chsum);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImei() {
        return imei;
    }

    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    public int getReadCycle() {
        return readCycle;
    }

    public void setReadCycle(int readCycle) {
        this.readCycle = readCycle;
    }

    public int getDataCount() {
        return dataCount;
    }

    public void setDataCount(int dataCount) {
        this.dataCount = dataCount;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public int getInterval1() {
        return interval1;
    }

    public void setInterval1(int interval1) {
        this.interval1 = interval1;
    }

    public int getInterval2() {
        return interval2;
    }

    public void setInterval2(int interval2) {
        this.interval2 = interval2;
    }

    public int getInterval3() {
        return interval3;
    }

    public void setInterval3(int interval3) {
        this.interval3 = interval3;
    }

    public int getBatP() {
        return batP;
    }

    public void setBatP(int batP) {
        this.batP = batP;
    }

    public int getBatV() {
        return batV;
    }

    public void setBatV(int batV) {
        this.batV = batV;
    }

    public int getChsum() {
        return chsum;
    }

    public void setChsum(int chsum) {
        this.chsum = chsum;
    }
}
```

JpaService:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;


public class JpaService {

    private static JpaService instance;

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private JpaService(){
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("port-reader");

    }

    public static synchronized JpaService getInstance() {
        return instance == null ? instance = new JpaService() : instance;
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        if(entityManagerFactory != null){
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }

    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```xml
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="port-reader" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<!--        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>-->
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sgt"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sgt-user"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sgtpass"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP3nj.png)

and the error I get:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p569w.png)

Is there's something wrong with my project structure or what am I missing?

Comment: How do you deploy on the server?

Comment: @Erwin, im just running it with java -jar nameofjar.jar

Comment: can you check if the `jakarta.persistence` jar actually exist in the server?

Comment: @Erwin i have to have it on server? i thought it has to be provided with my java application in builded jar.. sorry if im wrong. can you tell me where do i have to put it?

Comment: is it in the builded jar? have you check inside the jar?

Comment: yeah, it include jakarta.persistence

Comment: I think the problem is in the jar-loading ordering. Check your [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025261/12083015) to see the ordering, and I think it related with maven dependencies, try to move `jakarta.persistence` in the first order and then rebuild the jar

Comment: @Erwin You were right! Once i put jakarta.persistence on first place it worked! I had no idea its matters, i only thought it just has to be. Thank you a lot! i thought i'm going crazy

Comment: Add `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` to the `<manifest>` configuration of the `maven-jar-plugin`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks, problem fixed with Erwin comment above

Comment: @Elena did you solve it by re-ordering maven dependencies?

Comment: @DamienCooke not only re-ordering, i deleted all dependencies and add again,  and make sure i put jakarta.persistence in the first order and it worked

Comment: You may have had a 2.x version of the library on your classpath, which had all the classes in the old `javax.persistence` package (ostensibly to ease migration, although it actually just made it harder AND more confusing).

Answer (score -3):

1.Try With Another JDK Version like AWS Corette 11
example https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/
2.Check did you Correct Import Project
3Try to mvn clean ,mvn install

Comment: Thanks for advice, but i can only use JDK 16 or higher. And i also try mvn clean, mvn install - still same error

Comment: This is in no way a solution for the question.